# Trouble Executing GIT commands from outside bash shell (windows)

Tags: git, github-api, finalbuilder

I'm using finalbuilder to execute GIT commands without success.  FinalBuilder docs suggest setting the env variable HOME to %USERPROFILE% which I have done.  I can execute git clone commands successfully from the git bash shell but not from inside finalbuilder with their git action.

Leaving finalbuilder out of the picture, in windows, how can I execute a git command from outside of bash?

Now, my error is simply a timeout. no error, just timeout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Git for Windows and not the cygwin git - then provided the Program Files\Git\cmd folder is added to your PATH environment variable then you will be able to run git commands from the cmd prompt or any other shell. The bash prompt has its own PATH set up using the /etc/profile file which handles this separately. So `git version` should return the version you are running. If this is not enough to solve your issue you might consider providing that information along with the actual commands you run and which Windows version and platform you are on and so on.