# Finalbuilder 7 is there a way to use Git without ssh keys (using the HTTP address)?

Tags: git, finalbuilder

Issue: I've made a new finalbuilder project with one action, a Git Clone Repository. I have another finalbuilder project using Git over SSH that is working, therefore the initial setup of Git in finalbuilder is good. For this Git Clone test, instead of using the SSH for the repository address, I'm trying to use an HTTP address. It is a public repository on an internal server. When the action is run, the directory is created with directories of hooks, info, objects, and refs and some configuration files, but nothing from the repository I want to clone. The action then gets stuck in a running state unless I force stop the build. (Stop does not terminate a clone action.)

Question: My issue seems to be using the HTTP address for the repository instead of using SSH key connection, but I can't explain why this is an issue and haven't found anything on Google / Stackoverflow. Has anyone else experimented with this who could provide ideas of why this can't work or how to make it make it work? Does anyone know what is stuck in the Clone action? (I've allowed it to run up to a half hour, the repository is very small, it should take less then a minute.)

Git : version 1.9.4.msysgit.0
Finalbuilder 7.0.0.1724
We have Stash as a manager for Git repositories, I don't know if that would interfere.

References used so far:
Finalbuilder with Git over SSH: https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/articles/id/45/finalbuilder-server-and-git-over-ssh

Closest related Stackoverflow question with a similar issue:
[Trouble Executing GIT commands from outside bash shell (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867208/trouble-executing-git-commands-from-outside-bash-shell-windows)

Thank you for your time.
Note: I also posted the question here:
https://www.finalbuilder.com/support/forums/aft/16355

Comment: I guess you're certain that HTTP access has been granted to the git repository on your internal server? This would mean that this git repo is available to the general public (or at least via HTTP when you're on your local network). Another option would be to create an ssh key with no password for the user that will launch finalbuilder project...

Comment: (Sorry for the response delay, this is not a high priority project).

I've confirmed the HTTP access. 
The answer was found here;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github
posted answers allowed for using the git certificate security or simply putting the username/password in the http line. (poor security).